# Mongo express always crashes in docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: $$Admin123
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: xplorie
    # hostname: mongodb
    networks:
      mynetwork:
        ipv4_address: 172.19.0.20
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
    - /var/data/mongo:/data/db

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    environment:
      # ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongodb
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT: 27017
      # ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_USERNAME: admin
      # ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_PASSWORD: $$Admin123
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: admin
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: $$Admin123
      # ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME: admin
      # ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD: $$Admin123
    # networks:
    #   mynetwork:
    #     ipv4_address: 172.19.0.21
    volumes:
      - /var/data/mongoclient:/data/db
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    ports:
      - "3300:3000"
    restart: always


networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 172.19.0.0/24
        gateway: 172.19.0.1
```

but when I run this mongo express always crashes. this is the log:

```
mongo-express_1  | Welcome to mongo-express
mongo-express_1  | ------------------------
mongo-express_1  | 
mongo-express_1  | 
mongo-express_1  | (node:7) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
mongo-express_1  | Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://mongo:27017"
mongo-express_1  | (node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect [Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN mongo
mongo-express_1  |     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26) {
mongo-express_1  |   name: 'MongoNetworkError'
mongo-express_1  | }]
mongo-express_1  |     at Pool.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:441:11)
mongo-express_1  |     at Pool.emit (events.js:314:20)
mongo-express_1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:564:14
mongo-express_1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:1000:11
mongo-express_1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:32:7
mongo-express_1  |     at callback (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:300:5)
mongo-express_1  |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:330:7)
mongo-express_1  |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
mongo-express_1  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
mongo-express_1  |     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
mongo-express_1  |     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
mongo-express_1  |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
mongo-express_1  | (node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
mongo-express_1  | (node:7) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
deploy_mongo-express_1 exited with code 0
```

Comment: Mongo express container cannot resolve the address of your mongo database container. My guess: your mongo container is crashed.

Answer (score 0):

You have the mongo database container on one network (user defined) and the mongo-express container on the default bridge network. So they can't talk to each other.

Also, the hostname of the mongo db container is `mongodb`, so you should comment that back in.

Mongo express listens on port 8081, so that's the port you should map.

I'd just use the default bridge network and do something like this

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: $$Admin123
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: xplorie
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
    - /var/data/mongo:/data/db

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongodb
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: admin
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: $$Admin123
      # ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME: admin
      # ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD: $$Admin123
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    ports:
      - "3300:8081"
    restart: always
```

You should then be able to access Mongo express on `http://localhost:3300/`.

Be aware that Mongo will not create a database for you because you don't have any initialization scripts. From the docs: 'MongoDB is fundamentally designed for "create on first use", so if you do not insert data with your JavaScript files, then no database is created.'

Another thing is that Mongo Express is still alpha software and it tries to connect to the database immediately when it starts and that connection often fails because Mongo needs a little time to be ready. By setting `restart: always` as you have, you'll restart Express until the connection succeeds. But you might see a failed container or two on startup.

Comment: it kept crashing and didn't survive with this error Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://admin:$Admin123@mongodb:27017/"

Comment: can u suggest something other than mongo express that is more reliable?

Comment: Does it keep crashing (see the last paragraph in my answer)? Is your mongodb container running when you do `docker ps`? No, I don't know of an alternative to Mongo Express.

Comment: yes it is working fine. I can connect to it from my service. It's just that I cannot browse and view data that is already thetre. Off course I don't want to code to view all that data

Comment: Are you sure Express is not working? What's the status of the express container in `docker ps`? And have you tried going to `http://localhost:3300` in a browser?

Comment: is there a way i can post the full log file